# Rails 4: How to implement a frequent poll task (every 10 seconds)

Tags: multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4

folks.

I am working on a Rails 4 app that need to poll the network every 10s for some data.
The peers are small embedded systems that return a time_stamp and some data I post to the DB. I am using MRI 2.0.0 + Rails 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

In this fashion, I created a "singleton-like" service object in my application.rb and got it to run a synched polling Thread. This poller updates my ActiveRecord models into the DB.

I learned that Threading in not recommended in Ruby/Rails. But unfortunately I could not find any other solution. This polling mechanism is critical to the app data capture routines and is eating my time.

Now I've got under two "unkowns":

1> Is there any solution for this app structure? Is Threading a viable solution?
2> As I am still in dev mode there is only one "thin" running. Will my app brake when clustering 3 "thins" behind a nginx/apache deploy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), or [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). You want to have a separate process doing background task management, so your Rails application is primarily concerned with handling web requests, and not with background work.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Judy.

Actually you mention queue tools but I need a periodic 10s network poll to update App data and *probably* push to the DB =|

That is why I am "suffering" on this subject. Threads just work fine in dev. They dont seem very elegant, although. But they work.

Anyhow, I give Sidekiq a try and see what happens for now.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. Those libraries I mentioned are basically threads at their core, they're just a lot more elegant. They also allow you to split up the work between multiple machines, which you can't do with threads. I'm experienced with Delayed Job, and you'll find it quite easy to set up and start using.

Comment: Great!
Would DJ let me schedule a 10s poll?

I started thinking about having a memory table in my DB and use it as a shared scorecard with the polling results. Got to try a combined approach together w/ DJ. Reading the docs =]